# Using tapply across different permutations of columns

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
ID1   ID2   ID3   Area
1     2     2     20
1     3     2     30
1     2     2     90
2     3     2     80
2     2     1     70
2     3     1     67
3     2     1     73
```

I hope to use:

```
tapply(df$area, list = c(df$ID1, df$ID2), sum)
tapply(df$area, list = c(df$ID1, df$ID3), sum)
tapply(df$area, list = c(df$ID2, df$ID3), sum)
```

Is there a way to shorten this code? I have to do this iteratively over different ID codes and so I hope to reduce it.

Comment: Can you update your question with an expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to apply `tapply` to every combination of "`ID`" columns. We can select `"ID"` columns based on name and then use `combn` to create combination of column names and calculate `sum` with `tapply` for each combination.

```
cols <- grep("^ID", names(df), value = TRUE)
combn(cols, 2, function(x) tapply(df$Area, df[x], sum), simplify = FALSE)


#   ID2
#ID1   2   3
#  1 110  30
#  2  70 147
#  3  73  NA

#[[2]]
#   ID3
#ID1   1   2
#  1  NA 140
#  2 137  80
#  3  73  NA

#[[3]]
#   ID3
#ID2   1   2
#  2 143 110
#  3  67 110
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help today!

Comment: What if there's a 4th variable that I want to use tapply over?
combn(cols, 2, function(x) tapply(df$Area, list(df[x], df["var4"]), sum), simplify = FALSE) doesn't work -- returns error: arguments must have same length

Comment: @chu-js In that case, do `combn(cols, 2, function(x) tapply(df$Area, df[c(x, "var4")], sum), simplify = FALSE)`